# Change option keep url but change atribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
  <select name="sel" id="sel">
    <option value="11019403">Black/Charcoal</option>
    <option value="11019437">White/Navy</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

When changing any of the options remain selected and replaced by url:

`http://myadres.com/index2.php?adres=http//example.com/dadada` of `http://myadres.com/index2.php?adres=http//example.com/dadada?colcode=`

and there to fill value by option selected.

I apologize in advance but my English is not the strongest.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to format your code. It makes it easily readable for us

Comment: I don't understand your question. I think you have to try harder to explain.

Comment: Which attribute you want to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean that you want to redirect to a page when the select is changed.

The following will bind an onchange event to your select menu and redirect when it's changed:

```
<select name="sel" id="sel">
    <option value="11019403">Black/Charcoal</option>
    <option value="11019437">White/Navy</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sel").change(function() {
        window.location.href = 'http://myadres.com/index2.php?adres=http//example.com/dadada?colcode=' + $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cvL95/